# Euler-Lagrange equation in polar or cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have been studying Euler-Lagrange in Variation Calculus. I am comfortable with the formulation when the function under the integral is of the form `f = f(x, y)`. But I am unsure as to how this change for a function given in polar coordinates `f = f(r, theta)`

say

$\begin{equation*}
I\ ( u) \ =\ \int ^{1}_{0}\int ^{2\pi }_{0} F\left( r,\ \theta ,\ u,\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} ,\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta }\right) \ rd\theta dr
\end{equation*}$

so how would you calculate the variation, $\delta I $

Will it be

$ \delta I (u) = \int ^1_0 \int ^{2\pi}_0 (\frac {\partial F} {\partial u} + \frac {\partial F} {\partial u ^`_r} {\delta u ^`_r} + \frac {\partial F} {\partial u ^`_\theta} {\delta u ^`_\theta}   ) rd\theta dr$

I am confused about this, this seems incorrect, what should be done with the $r$ at the end?
Also how do I apply Gauss divergence theorem at the end to seperate the boundary conditions from the rest of the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just define $G=F \cdot r$, use the standard methods (treating $r$ and $\theta$ the same as cartesian coordinates), and transform back to $F$ at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much. Doing as you say I would get the Euler-Lagrange equation and the following part  $
\begin{equation*}
 \int ^{1}_{0}\int ^{2\pi }_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial u^{'}_{r}} \delta u\right) \ +\ \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial u^{'}_{\theta }} \delta u\right) \ d\theta dr
\end{equation*}$  Can you also help me with how I can apply the Gauss divergence theorem on this to get the natural boundary conditions?

Comment: Does doing it the same as for cartesian coordinates not work?

Comment: With cartesian I'd use Gauss divergence theorem at this point to get the natural BCs which are of the form  $\begin{equation*}
I\ ( u) \ =\ \int ^{1}_{0}\int ^{1}_{0}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u^{'}_{x}} \delta u\right) \ +\ \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial u^{'}_{y}} \delta u\right) \ dxdy
\end{equation*}$ which then equals ... (second comment)

Comment: $
\begin{equation*}
\oint _{s}\left(\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u^{'}_{x}}\right) \ \overrightarrow{n_{x}} +\ \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial u^{'}_{y}}\right)\overrightarrow{n_{y}} \ \right) \delta u\ ds
\end{equation*}$  (n being the unit vector)
I don't know how to apply the same thing here

Comment: But you now have an integral equation over a rectangle, its exactly the same. Just substitute $r=x$, $\theta=y$ and see how far you can get forgetting about polar coordinates.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, that's what I was unsure of.